# Java application which was loaded earlier through app-v not working after we had installed Java family locally

Tags: java

We have a Java application which loads through separate JRE Version 1.7.0_17(Both application and JRE version in the same bubble).

But now we had configured Java family locally to all the user desktops.
From then when we are trying to launch the application through App-V Browser is hanging and we are unable to launch the application.(Not even till login page)

But when we tried launching the application manually , i mean putting the URL directly to the web browser which uses Java family installed locally it was loading fine.

I would like to know the reason why the application is not loading through App-V after installation of Java family(all JRE versions of 1.7 till 1.7.0_80) locally.

Comment: Did you check the application log or server logs, you may find some helpful information from logs.

Comment: i don't find any errors,but my java application is with applets.Will it make any conflict with the browser plug in which our Java family and virtualisation client using?

Comment: I'm not familiar with App-V, but your installed JRE and browser Java plugin needs to be in sync, plug-in is kind of a bridge between browser and the JRE (which is running on the system). So there could be a conflict if they are not in sync.